# How can i set settings propperties in charms bar in XAML, Windows 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, settings, charms-bar

I'm trying to get the charms bar working in windows 8, but i can't find any thing using google.

What i want is to let users acces settings and privacy policy throuw charms bar.

I all ready have this:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += MainPage_CommandsRequested;
    }

    void MainPage_CommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand("commandid", "Settings", DoOperation));
    }

    private async void DoOperation(IUICommand command)
    {
        //Show the Settings or Privacy Policy HERE!
    }
```

I don't know how i can get my settings in place of: //Show the Settings or Privacy Policy HERE!

Any help or rather code samples would be greate.

Comment: I'm not getting your problem..could you explain what your need and what you have done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better if you put the code in App.xaml.cs, here's a working example:

```
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{ /....
   SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnCommandsRequested;
   //before if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof...
}
void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
          var privacy =  new SettingsCommand("privacyPref", "Privacy Plicy",
            (uiCommand) => { Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://YOURURL.COM")); });
        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(privacy);
        var preferences = new SettingsCommand("preferences", "Preferences", (handler) =>
        {
            var settings = new SettingsFlyout(); //Callisto extension
            settings.Content = new PreferencesUserControl(); //Add New Element->User Control
            settings.HeaderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(_background);
            settings.Background = new SolidColorBrush(_background);
            settings.HeaderText = "Preferences";
            settings.IsOpen = true;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you also have the classes for me? which you used in your example

Comment: Look at the code, SettingsFlyout is in the Callisto extension and PreferencesUserControl need to be created and defined by you and put the things you want in there.

Comment: This worked, but i have one problem.
i set this on the first page(the homescreen) and every time i go to an other page and come back to the homescreen he ads an other button to the charmsbar.
is there a way to check if button is added?

Comment: Don't put it on the MainPage, put it on App.xaml.cs, that's why I also put the OnLaunched method, because it needs to be in the OnLaunched method in App.xaml.cs

Comment: i tryed you code but the app doesn't know SettingsFlyout(); are you using some nuget packages?

Comment: Check the comment on the code, SettingsFlyout is from the Callisto extension

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample for [App Setting](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/app-settings-sample-1f762f49).

When you fully understand this you can try to understand [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CharmFlyout-A-Metro-Flyout-25fe53b6)

Which is better than above sample. Above sample is easy to understand as compared to this sample

Answer (score 0):

There has been quite a few questions about Settings/About implementations.  This is about the easiest I have found
http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/how-to-create-windows-8-settings-pane.html